# seaborn - facet grid of column values

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

With a pandas `dataframe` like below

```
Date,Id_x,EC Id,ActDlS,pmAcUlPr
4/27/2020,1139,1139,1131,6
4/28/2020,1139,1139,1131,6
4/29/2020,1139,1139,1131,6
4/30/2020,1139,1139,1131,6
5/1/2020,1140,1140,1132,6
```

Need to create a chart for all the columns by the `Date` column like below using `seaborn`. There could be 100s of such columns in the real dataset.

I was trying to use the example in [Seaborn doc](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html)

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="time", row="smoker")
```

Need help to get the dataset in the format that could be accepted in `sns.FacetGrid`

[image]

Comment: Are the graphs in your question representing the expected output ?

Comment: Yes, those are the graphs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use FacetGrid in your case: you are not plotting one graph per value in `Date`. Instead, you need to use `plt.subplot`.

It will look like this:

```py
# defining number of rows and columns
ncols = 2
nrows = len(df) % ncols + 1


# creation of figure and axes
fig, axes = plt.subplots(
    nrows=nrows,
    ncols=ncols,
    sharey=True,
    figsize=(ncols*5, nrows*4)
)

# loop for plotting each column
for i, col in enumerate(df):
    sns.barplot(x=df.index, y=df[col],
                ax=axes[i % 2, i // 2], color='royalblue').set_title(col)

fig.tight_layout()
```

[image: Result]

Comment: as you would see in the question, the y-axis for all charts need to have the same axis range.

Comment: @user3206440 I edited my answer adding `sharey=True`. If you want the same ranges for the x-axis as well, just add `sharex=True` as well.